# Array Length Not Matching Index Length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I really can't figure out how to get around this error `array length 488 does not match index length 9914`. I think it's got something to do with how I'm defining my dataframes but I really can't find where the problem lies.

my code is:

```
   train_df.drop(['key','passenger_count','dropoff_longitude','dropoff_latitude','pickup_longitude','pickup_latitude','pickup_datetime'],axis=1,inplace=True)
test_df.drop(['passenger_count','dropoff_longitude','dropoff_latitude','pickup_longitude','pickup_latitude','pickup_datetime'],axis=1,inplace=True)

train_df.dropna(how = 'any', axis = 'rows', inplace=True)
train_df.isnull().sum()

y = train_df.pop('fare_amount')
x = train_df
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(x_train, label=y_train)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(x_test, label=y_test)
param = {
    'max_depth':5,
    'nthread':4,
    'eval_metric': 'rmse',
    'min_child_weight': 1,
    'eta':0.3
}
model = xgb.train(param, dtrain)
pred = model.predict(dtest, ntree_limit=model.best_ntree_limit)
submission = pd.DataFrame({"key":test_df["key"], "fare_amount": pred},
                         columns = ['key', 'fare_amount']
```

)

The error is occurring in the last line where `submission` is and the traceback looks like:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-193-1cb42e5ec957> in <module>()
     57 pred = model.predict(dtest, ntree_limit=model.best_ntree_limit)
     58 submission = pd.DataFrame({"key":test_df["key"], "fare_amount": pred},

ValueError: array length 488 does not match index length 9914
```

Both datasets start off with the same columns, but `test.csv` doesn't have `fare_amount`

And the shape of `test.csv` before I drop any columns is `(9914,8)`, whereas `train.csv` has `(3034,9)`

Comment: Whats the shape of `test_df.key` and `pred`?

Comment: @RafaelC `pred.shape` is `(488,)` and `test_df.key` shape is `(9914,)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to fix the problem I added a new variable `x_predict = test_df.drop("key", axis=1)` and then added that to `prediction = model.predict(xgb.DMatrix(x_pred), ntree_limit = model.best_ntree_limit)`

Answer (score 0):

You are predicting using dataset "dtest", which is a subset of train_df. While test_df is a separate dataset.

Even if both test_df and pred have same length, they are 2 different dataset and linking them is pointless unless **test_df = train_df**

And even if they are similar, you will need to do the same DataFrame transformation on test_df as you did on train_df before linking them together.